# Is there a way to execute a task before anything else happens?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, async-await

I need to fetch some data before passing it to a `View`. I created a ViewModel `BoughtItemViewModel` for the my `BoughtItemView`.

For simplicity I only provide one case, my enum has some more cases I switch through depending on what item is bought. This is the `BoughtItemView`:

```
enum SomeType {
    case song(Song)
}
struct BoughtItemCard: View {
    @State var type: SomeType
    @StateObject var vm = BoughtItemViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        switch type {
        case .song(let song):
            WebImage(url: URL(string: song.image))
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .overlay(BoughtItemOverlay(type: type)
                .environmentObject(vm)
                .onAppear() {
                        vm.fetchUnlockDate(path: "songs", docId: song.id ?? "")
      }
   }
}
```

This is the `BoughtItemViewModel`:

```
class BoughtItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var unlockDate = Date()
    
    func fetchUnlockDate(path: String, docId: String) {
        let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid  ?? ""
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection(path)
        .document(docId).collection("unlocked").document(uid).getDocument { docSnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            let data = docSnapshot?.data()
            self.unlockDate = (data?["unlockDate"] as? Date ?? Date())
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want the `unlockDate`in my `BoughtItemOverlay` View to show the fetched date.
Again for simplicity I provide one case, this is the `BoughtItemOverlay`:

```
struct BoughtItemOverlay: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false
    @State var type: SomeType
    @State var unlockDate = Date()
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: BoughtItemViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        switch type {
        case .song(let song):
            VStack {
                Spacer().onAppear() {
                    unlockDate = vm.unlockDate
                }
                Text("Purchased \(unlockDate.formatted(.dateTime.day().month(.defaultDigits).year()))")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Instead of displaying the `unlockDate` it always displays the date of today. I'm not sure why that is since the `BoughtItemOverlay`should refresh after the State changes in the `onAppear()` setting the value to the `BoughtItemViewModel` value. Atleast that I think it should work that way, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase returns a FIRTimestamp so I had to change my code to:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class BoughtItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var unlockDate = Date()
    
    func fetchUnlockDate(path: String, docId: String) {
        let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid  ?? ""
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection(path).document(docId).collection("unlocked").document(uid).getDocument { docSnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            let data = docSnapshot?.data()
            let timestamp = data?["unlockDate"] as? Timestamp
            self.unlockDate = timestamp?.dateValue() ?? Date()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `@State var unlockDate = Date()` you are creating a new source of truth and try to synchronize it with `unlockDate = vm.unlockDate`.

Don´t do that, use the Viewmodel itself in your Childview:

```
struct BoughtItemOverlay: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false
    @State var type: SomeType
    
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: BoughtItemViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        switch type {
        case .song(let song):
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                // use the vm value here
                Text("Purchased \(vm.unlockDate.formatted(.dateTime.day().month(.defaultDigits).year()))")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The Viewmodel will notify the View when `unlockDate` has changed and the View will show the new date.

Comment: That makes sense, yet the date is still showing todays date, something is wrong in the fetching func itself when trying to unwrap data

Comment: I solved it. The data in my database was wrong. I didn't have any unlockedDate saved